# Android Firebase Query for near Timestamps (and close Locations if possible)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm a newbie with Firebase and I implemented it in my earthquake sensing Android app. My structure looks like

[image: this]

So, everytime my app senses an earthquake it makes an entry in Firebase like above. What I want to do though is use data from other devices as well to determine if the earthquake was legit or not. Specifially, every time 1 device senses one, I wanna check the firebase if in the last minute there was another entry from another device as well (ideally I would want to also check the coordinates to see if it's at a nearby location but I saw that this is more tough to accomplish so you can skip that). Any idea of how this is possible? Basically, I just want to check if new entries within 1 minute of my entry exist (I could also make a check after 1 minute, in case my device was the first to detect it).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: Currently I'm kinda stuck on this. I have successfully inserted the data into the firebase and I was thinking that maybe onDataChange or with onChildAdded something could help but not sure :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries are a multi-step process:

1. Order the data on a specific property value.
2. Determine a start node and/or end node to return (sometimes called a slice).
3. Optionally limit the number of nodes to return.

In Android that'd look something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Earthquakes");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt("2020-11-03 18:12:00").endAt("2020-11-03 18:12:59").
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot quakeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("DB", quakeSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.i("DB", quakeSnapshot.child("eventType").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

I highly recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [reading](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) and [querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) data, and taking the [Codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: Sorry, 1 more question. If I want to check the user's value in the results that the query got back, how can I do that?

Comment: That's be: `quakeSnapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class)`